# ActiveRecord::Relation query for grouped objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models `User`, `Subject` and `Grade`.

```
class User< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :grades
end

class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :grades
end

class Grade < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :subject
end
```

User can have several grades for the same subject.

On the user's page, I would like to display his `average` and `maximum` grade for each subject.
What is the best way to accomplish it?

```
User: Qwerty
Grades:
-------------------------------
subject       average   maximum
-------------------------------
"subject_1"   56        97
"subject_2"   45        85
```

As far as I know, [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) has special methods for `maximum` and `average`, but I don't know how to get `ActiveRecord::Relation`-object for each group of grades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need something like:

```
user.grades.joins(:subject).
  group(:subject_id).
  select(['MAX(grades.grade) as max', 'AVG(grades.grade) as avg', subjects: :name])
```

Comment: Thanks for great solution! By the way, it seems like without `.joins(:subject)`, query still works correctly.